# Python Google Drive API Slow Multi-File Upload

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to upload a directory and all of its contents to Google Drive. I can accomplish this in Python fine and the files upload, but it goes 1 file at a time with a request to the API with each file and its very slow. I'm practicing with a small directory for now, but when I have 2000 files in the future it will take for-ev-er. Is there a faster way I can accomplish it, maybe with a single request instead of a request for each file?

Thanks

Here is my main program:

```
# user wants to upload to Google Drive HOME-SYNC
print("4: upload to HOME-SYNC on Google Drive")

# assuming HOME-SYNC is empty, for now first step is copying directory
# structure on local machine to HOME-SYNC
# in the future need to ask if want to backup HOME-SYNC first, and if 
# so back it up
# then need to empty it

# specify the start path
start_path = "/home/geoff/HOME-SYNC"
start_path = ff.abs_path_from_user_input(start_path)
print("START PATH")
print(start_path)

# create a directory object with start path
start_directory = Directory(start_path)

# create a google drive service resource
google_service = ff.create_google_token()

# create the directory tree on google drive
# '1YOTDKowprC2Paq95X-MIKSUG_vpuViQw' is the id of HOME-SYNC on 
# Google Drive
start_directory.create_google_drive_tree(
    'HOME-SYNC', 
    google_service, 
    '1YOTDKowprC2Paq95X-MIKSUG_vpuViQw')

print("FINISHED")
```

Here is my Directory Class:

```
class Directory():

    def __init__(self, directory_path):
        """Initialize directory"""
        self.directory_path = directory_path
        #print("__INIT__ DIR PATH=" + self.directory_path)

    def create_google_drive_tree(
        self, 
        google_drive_folder="", 
        google_service=False,
        parent_dir_id=''):
        """Creates the same tree in google drive that is in the Directory
        object, with 'google_drive_folder' as the ROOT directory
        (== Directory obj)"""
        # google_drive_folder = name of the current directory
        # google_service = Google API resource
        # parent_dir_id = id of the parent dir on Google drive

        # create the files_and_dirs list in the current directory
        files_and_dirs = \
            [files_and_dirs for files_and_dirs in listdir(self.directory_path)]            
        print(files_and_dirs)
        # sorts the files and dirs so their alphabetical and files come first
        files_and_dirs = \
            ff.sort_files_and_dirs(self.directory_path, files_and_dirs)        
        # loop through files and directories, outputting if its a file or dir
        # if its a dir and full_tree==true, make a recursive call by creating 
        # new Directory instance then listing the contents of that as well
        for fd in files_and_dirs:
            abs_path = ff.abs_path_from_local_dir(self.directory_path, fd)
            if ff.check_file_or_dir(abs_path) == "file":
                # its a file
                # need to copy the file to Google Drive
                file_metadata = {
                    'name': fd,
                    'parents': [parent_dir_id]
                }
                media = MediaFileUpload(abs_path)
                file = google_service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                                    media_body=media,
                                                    fields='id').execute()
            else:
                # its a directory
                # create the directory in google drive
                file_metadata = {
                    'name': fd,
                    'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
                    'parents': [parent_dir_id]
                }
                file = google_service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                                    fields='id').execute()
                # create a new Directory obj with the current Directory
                # which is a subdirectory of the current Directory
                sub_dir = Directory(abs_path)                
                # Recursively build tree inside the subdirectory
                sub_dir.create_google_drive_tree(
                    fd, 
                    google_service, 
                    file.get('id'))
```

and I have utility functions in file_functions.py

```
def abs_path_from_user_input(start_path):
    if start_path[:1] == '/':
        path_type = "absolute"
    else:
        path_type = "relative"
    if path_type != "absolute":
        start_path = realpath(start_path)
    return start_path

def abs_path_from_local_dir(directory, content):
    abs_path = realpath(join(directory, content))    
    return abs_path

def sort_files_and_dirs(curr_path, files_and_dirs):
    files = []
    dirs = []
    for file_dir in files_and_dirs:
        abs_path = abs_path_from_local_dir(curr_path, file_dir)
        if check_file_or_dir(abs_path) == "file":
            files.append(file_dir)
        else:
            dirs.append(file_dir)
    files.sort()
    dirs.sort()
    combined = []
    for f in files:
        combined.append(f)
    for d in dirs:
        combined.append(d)
    return combined         

def check_file_or_dir(path):
    if not exists(path):
        print("ERROR: PATH IS NOT VALID: " + path)
        return False;
    else:
        if isfile(path):
            return "file"
        else:
            return "dir"


def is_valid_dir(path):
    if exists(path):
        # the path is a valid path
        if not isfile(path):
            # its a valid directory
            return True
        else:
            # its a valid file, but we want directories
            return False
    else:
        # the path doesnt exist
        return False

def create_google_token():
    store = file.Storage('credentials.json')
    creds = store.get()
    if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    # service resource is the connection to google drive
    service = build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
    return service
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1 file at a time with a request to the API with each file and its very slow.

Uploading does take time.

> Is there a faster way I can accomplish it, maybe with a single request instead of a request for each file?

There is no batch method for uploading files.  you will need to upload your files one at a time as you are doing now.   Remember there is a quota limit on this your only going to be able upload so fast.  You could consider multi threading this and running a version of your script for each of the files to upload.  However i wouldn't advise this as its going to be the same user and your going to end up having quota and flooding errors.

Note: you can batch the metadata upload but thats really not going to solve your problem [batching request.](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/batch)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess I'll just have to be selective in the files i upload/download i was hoping to sync my Home directory in its entirety but unnecessary uploads would clearly cause it to take way too long. Would you happen to know if the upload speed using python and REST faster/slower than just dragging and dropping files, or the same speed?

Comment: my python knowledge is limited sorry.  If you are taking about dragging and dropping them into some official application created by Google then it may in act be faster as google would not put the same limitations on their products as they do on third party developers.